# why display css code in the content in Safari of question2answer system?

Tags: safari, question2answer

I installed question2answer on my mac and i login by Safari and ask a question, after posted the question, i view the question, there is a strange line in the content:

## next_pages_container { width: 5px; hight: 5px; position: absolute; top: -100px; left: -100px; z-index: 2147483647 !important; } test question

but it works fine if i use Chrome.

I think this code line is a css code, i don't know why it's display in the content.

Anybody can help me? thanks.

Comment: i searched all php,javascript,css files there are no this string: "next_pages_container"?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is a bug in "Evernote Web Clipper" for Safari:
http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/26375-help-clipper-injects-clearly-html-into-my-pages/

The clipper inserts the code in all editable areas. The suggested workaround is to disable the clipper.